# How can I delete an empty value created in a Python list?

Tags: python

I want to delete the empty values which are being created in Python list.

My code here - https://pastebin.com/whz7t4yR

I tried to solve 'String Task' problem from [Codeforces](https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/118/A)
Every time a letter is found, I'm inserting a dot after that letter in the list. But an empty value is being created after that dot insertion.

I've tried to delete the empty values. But apparently, it only works for a particular test case("Codeforces"). For other two test cases, it shows

> "IndexError: list index out of range"

```
for l in range(0,len(s)):    
    if(s[l] in letter and s[l+1] in letter):
        s.insert(l+1, '.')
        print("inside IF, index[",l,"]=>", s[l])
    elif(s[l] in letter):
        s.insert(l+1,'.')
        #del (s[l+2])
        print("inside ELIF, index[",l,"]=>", s[l])
    else:
        print("inside ELSE, index[",l,"]=>", s[l])
        continue
```

Expected result:

```
 .c.d.f.r.c.s
```

Actual result:

```
 .c.d.f.r.cs
```

Comment: post code as part of your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
for l in range(0,len(s)):
    if(...s[l+1]...)
```

These are in your first two lines, `l+1` is guaranteed to get out of range of your list `s`

If you need to access the next element like this, change the range to `for l in range(0,len(s)-1):` instead so you know you'll always have a `s[l+1]` element

Answer (score 0):

Try this. The complete solution.

```
st = input()
vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u','y']
for i in st.lower():
    if i not in vowels:
        print(f'.{i}', end='')
```

Comment: Also 'y' should be in vowels. Anyway, thank you so much!

Comment: If this helped you with your problem, you can accept the answer. :-P

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this easier method for the question:

```
    word = input("").lower()
    no_Vowel = word.translate({ord(change): None for change in "aoyeui"})
    no_VowelsPoint = f".{no_Vowel}"
    points = ".".join(no_Vowels).replace("..", ".")
    print(points.lower())
```